# OpenCL support hardware requirements

Tags: windows, gpu, opencl, opencv

Does my machine support [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)? I found *[Conformant Products](http://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products/)* where the list contains the required hardware requirements. Please find the below screenshots of few of my machine. Does any one of the below support OpenCL?

Screenshot from machine 1:

[image]

Screenshot from machine 2:

[image]

Screenshot from machine 3:

[image]

Does any of my three machines support OpenCL? Or do all the three support OpenCL? I am trying to run a basic OpenCL face-detection program and am failing. I have posted Stack Overflow question *[How to run basic OpenCL face detection code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475003)* regarding the same.

After running [GPU Caps Viewer](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/), the "1st machine" is of type **GPU 1: Intel HD Graphics 2000**. Does it support OpenCL?

Comment: I have Radeon HD6490M in my laptop and it supports OpenCL1.1, so I guess yours will definitely support that

Answer (score 1):

Intel's OpenCL supports Intel Core CPUs for the CPU-only version and 3rd and 4th generation Intel Core CPUs for the built-in GPUs.  Your first screen-shot does not tell me enough to know which generation of Intel HD graphics card is installed, but your 3rd PC definitely won't support OpenCL on its Intel GPU (HD 3000 was for 2nd generation Intel Core CPUs).  PC 3 does support Intel's CPU-runtime for OpenCL.

AMD's OpenCL CPU-runtime should work on the 3rd PC too, but you have not given enough info about the other two for me to advise you there.  That said, AMD's OpenCL CPU runtime supports a lot of CPUs so it is worth attempting to install it.

The Nvidia GPU on the 2nd PC is too old so it does not have OpenCL support (it pre-dates OpenCL by about 3 years).

Comment: for the first screen shot there is no much details of the driver. It simply says Intel(HD) graphics family. Can please advice how to check the details. I have tried all the ways.

Comment: Run dxdiag.exe (Start menu -> Run -> type in dxdiag.exe and run it).

Comment: I have updated the question with screen shot of my machine which says "GPU 1: Intel HD Graphics 2000", does this machine supports opencl?

Comment: The Intel HD Graphics 2000 GPU does not support OpenCL, however the CPU runtime libraries from both AMD and Intel will run on that CPU as it is a 2nd generation Intel Core CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [GPU-Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPU-Z). It has information about what models of GPU programming are supported.

Comment: That will tell 2vision2 which OpenCL platforms have been installed and which of the installed devices they work with.  The only draw back is that the OP would have to download the AMD and Nvidia drivers, the AMD APP SDK and the Intel OpenCL SDK to find out what works - not very efficient.

Comment: isn't it the best way to find out? I assume she/he will either code OpenCL or use applications that use OpenCL.

Comment: Some of those SDKs/drivers are over 150MB.  People using capped and/or slow internet connections won't want to download so much only to find some of it does not work on their hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install GPU Caps Viewer from this website: http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/

It is even more complete than GPU-Z and allow you to run OpenCL and DirectX demos.

I am actually interested in what kind of face-detection program you are trying to run. OpenCL is widely used for boosting the performance on heavy computational tasks but I haven't heard of any software that uses it for improving face-detection. Is it free? Could you share here?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the steps OP should take to solve his problem (screenshots are welcomed)? It also appears that the OP tried to use GPU Caps Viewer from the same website.